# Android layout set two buttons centered vertically and horizontally

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing an Android application.

I'm trying to set buttons save and close centered, but they appear to the left.

Here is my XML layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialogGameName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialogGameDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2sp"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/registerGameButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/save"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0sp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/closeButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/close" 
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't really center anything unless it's parent is bigger than it.  You have the parent to the buttons as wrap_content, so there's no room to center... try this for the buttons:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/registerGameButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="save"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0sp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/closeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="close" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Add:

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

To your horisontal linear layout, the one which contains your two buttons.

The "android:layout_gravity" decides how the the view should position itself in it's parent, while "android:gravity" decides how the views children should be aligned

Answer (score 1):

Some tips for u (The change i made in your xml)

- `android:layout_gravity` is for the layout for its child we need to set `android:gravity`
- to get exact center we set `android:gravity="center"`
- In order to set the child in exact center the parent should be with `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` and `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`
- if that layout is a child of any other layout its should also be with `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` and `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`

  ```
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/dialogGameName"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_marginBottom="2sp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
      android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
      android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
      android:text="asdff"
      android:typeface="sans"
      android:textSize="26sp"
      android:textStyle="bold"/>
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/dialogGameDescription"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="left"
      android:text="asdff"
      android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
      android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
      android:layout_marginTop="2sp"
      android:typeface="monospace"
      android:textSize="18sp"/>

  <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:gravity="center">
      <Button
          android:id="@+id/registerGameButton"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/save"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
          android:layout_marginRight="2sp"
          android:layout_marginTop="0sp" />
      <Button
          android:id="@+id/closeButton"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/close" 
          android:gravity="center"
          android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="2sp"
          android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
          android:layout_marginTop="0sp"/>
  </LinearLayout>
  ```

Comment: It's not necessary to set android:layout_height="fill_parent" to make it work.